# jquery and mootools conflict - one script works, another don't

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Ok, I use mootools to display flash content through google maps and I work hard to make it work properly, so there is little chance to switch it to jQuery. On the other side, I see jQuery more useful to every other things so I'm trying to make it work together. That's for explanation. Now here is the code.

this jQuery script I use to show/hide animation and it works with mootools perfectly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
 jQuery('#slickbox').hide();
 // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
  jQuery('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    jQuery('#slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

recently, I added scrit to animate flowing menu and I can't get it work. I've tried to apply noConflict, but it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var name = "#floatMenu";
var menuYloc = null;
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        menuYloc = parseInt($j(name).css("top").substring(0,$j(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
        $j(window).scroll(function () { 
            offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
            $j(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:500,queue:false});
        });
    }); 
 </script>
```

Error message is Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'dispose'
Thank you very much.

Comment: You're still using $ in `$(document)`

Comment: I've edited my post and add error message.  You're right Dr.Molle, I fixed it, but still the same problem with the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format your code this way, and there is <strike>no need to use `noConflict()`.</strike> Call `jQuery.noConflict();` right after the jQuery and MooTools library have been loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    var name = "#floatMenu",
        menuYloc = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
        $(window).scroll(function () { 
            var offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
            $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:500,queue:false});
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This will encapsulate your code to a function, which will be passed the `jQuery` object. Anywhere you use `$` inside that function it will reference `jQuery`.

Also, there is no attribute `language` with the value `"text/javascript"`, it's the `type` attribute, which should have that value. Don't use the `language` attribute anymore.

Comment: Thank you, Shef. Unfortunatelly, it won't work. jQuery part work ok, but mootools don't. Still the same error message. I've uploaded it with your code here: http://www.turie.eu/hlavna3

Comment: The mootools part I mean when you click on binocular icon on the map, ther have to display lightbox clone (bumpbox) window. I've tried all tips here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries , but nothing works for me. Thank you again!

Comment: Okay, updated my answer. You should call `jQuery.noConflict();` right after both libraries have been loaded.

Comment: Shef, it works! Thank you. But after I added that call(jQuery.noConflict();), there is still one error message: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://turie.eu/hlavna3/ from frame with URL http://turie.eu/hlavna3/. Domains, protocols and ports must match. (I've updated the code on server)

Comment: @culter: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url) for an answer to that problem.

Comment: Yes, i'm working on it. Anyway, this question is answered. Thank you!