# How to send user-created HTML to W3C validator for automatic checking—without cross-domain errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, w3c-validation

I am writing an application for users, in which they input valid HTML into a text field.

I have a button in jQuery which tries to load the text field area into the W3C validator:

```
$('#inspecthtml').on('click', function() {
             var storyhtml = $('#story').text();
             validatorurl= "http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input";
             var newWin = open(validatorurl,'Validator','height=600,width=600');
             newWin.onload = function() {
                 newWin.document.getElementById("fragment").value=storyhtml;
             }           
    });
```

I get an error message in the console (using Chrome):

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://api.flattr.com/button/view/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2F&title=View%20W3C-Validator%20on%20flattr.com&
>   from frame with URL http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. The
>   frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'flattr.com', but the
>   frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to
>   the same value to allow access.

I attribute this to the cross domain security (see [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url))

My question: Is there a way to send the data to the validator, so my users can check their own mark-up?

Comment: How is this any better than just having a link to the validator?

Comment: Have you looked into jsonp?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, one less step, and less user training.  If they "see the green line", they know it is good.

Comment: @jchapa, no, can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: @Sable: I would be afraid to let people who need training to use the W3C validator to write any code in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code snippet below will you can get the same effect and user experience you’re after.

It’s written using jQuery’s `$.ajax(…)` with some `DOMParser` and `document.write(…)` to put the styled results and UI of the W3C HTML Checker into a new window the way it seems you want.

```js
var validator_baseurl= "https://validator.w3.org/nu/";
var validator_requesturl = validator_baseurl
    + "?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes";
$.ajax({
    url: validator_requesturl,
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: storyhtml,
    contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        var results = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(response, "text/html");
        results.querySelector("link[rel=stylesheet]").href
            = validator_baseurl + "style.css";
        results.querySelector("script").src
            = validator_baseurl + "script.js";
        results.querySelector("form").action
            = validator_requesturl;
        var newWin = window.open("about:blank",
            "Checker results", "height=825,width=700");
        newWin.document.open();
        newWin.document.write(results.documentElement.outerHTML);
        newWin.document.close();
        newWin.location.hash = "#textarea";
        setTimeout(function() {
            newWin.document.querySelector("textarea").rows = "5";
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

---

#### Explanation

- causes a POST request to be sent to the [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)
- makes the `storyhtml` text the POST body
- makes `text/html;charset=utf-8` the POST body’s media type (what the checker expects)
- causes the checker to actually check the `storyhtml` contents automatically
- shows the checker results in a new window right when it’s first opened, in one step (so your users don’t need to do a second step to manually submit it for checking themselves)
- replaces relative URLs for the checker’s frontend CSS+JS with absolute URLs (otherwise in this “standalone window” context, the CSS wouldn’t get applied, and the script wouldn’t run)
- `newWin.location.hash = "#textarea"` is needed to make the checker show the textarea

---

#### Notes

- intentionally uses the current [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (not the legacy W3C markup validator)
- intentionally sends the content to be checked as a POST body, not `multipart/form-data`); the checker supports `multipart/form-data` but making it a POST body is easier and better
- the `setTimeout` `textarea` bit isn’t required; I just put it to make the results visible without scrolling (bottom part of new window below textarea); you can of course remove it if you want
- sets the new window’s height and width a bit larger than the 600x600 in the question’s original code; again, I just did that to make things easier to see; change them however you want
- uses standard DOM ops that may have better jQuery methods/idioms (I don’t normally use jQuery, so I can imagine there are ways to streamline the code in it further around JQuery)
- could of course also be done without using jQuery at all—using standard [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or XHR instead (and I’d be happy to also add examples here that use Fetch and XHR if desired)
- tested & works as expected in Edge, Firefox, Chrome & Safari; but as with any code that uses `document.open`, Safari users need to unset *Preferences > Security > Block pop-up windows*

Comment: This looks like a really good answer, and makes sense, and I will give you a +1 for the detailed analysis.  However, it is a bit to implement, so it will take me some time to evaluate.  Once I do (assuming it works), I will give it the acceptance check mark.