# Javascript message within iframe

Tags: javascript, security, cross-browser, dom-events

I have this error while running a html file in Chrome:

> iframe  Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http‍://my_server.com/param from frame with URL http‍://another_server/example.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Is there a way so I can run the Javascript in different server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `hash` not the `url` itself. There are many similar questions in stackoverflow regarding this issue. [You can try check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324108/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url).